# Подскажите библиотеку, чтобы имитировать input type="date"

Tags: javascript, html, library

Тэг `<input type="date">` ведёт себя по разному в разных браузерах, поэтому мне нужна библиотека, которая позволит имитировать этот тэг, чтобы в разных браузерах всё было одинаково.

Comment: Вам нужен Bootstrap? : https://getbootstrap.com

Comment: @Pilaton Возможно ли взять лишь инпут для даты из бутстрапа? Остальное мне просто не нужно

Comment: У версии 3.4 есть возможность сконфигурировать и скачать только нужное [Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/). У новых версий такого уже нет и обычно я вручную вырезал нужный CSS из их файлов на [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/dist/css/bootstrap.css). Вы можете просто использовать версию 3.4, её не удалят.

Comment: @Pilaton Благодарю Вас за помощь!